# golang regex to capture text between a quote and a /

Tags: regex, go

my strings:

```
12345:cluster/ecs52v-usw2-tst",
12345:cluster/test32-euw1-stg",
```

The output I'm looking for is:  
ecs52v-usw2-tst
test32-euw1-stg

I have multiple cluster names that I'm trying to capture in a slice
I've gotten it in ruby `(?<=\/)(.*(tst|stg|prd))(?=")` but I'm having trouble in golang.
https://go.dev/play/p/DyYr3igu2CF

Comment: Are all lines formatted like this? Then you don't need a regex, but can for example use a Scanner to read line-per-line, split on slash, and ignore the last character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FindAllStringSubmatch](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) to find all submatches.

```golang
func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?mi)(/(.*?)")`)
    var str = `cluster/ecs52v-usw2-tst",
cluster/ecs52v-usw2-stg",
cluster/ecs52v-usw2-prd",`

    matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)
    for _, match := range matches {
        fmt.Printf("val = %s \n", match[2])
    }
}
```

Output

```
val = ecs52v-usw2-tst 
val = ecs52v-usw2-stg 
val = ecs52v-usw2-prd
```

https://go.dev/play/p/_LRVYaM2r7z

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?mi)/(.*?)"`)
    var str = `cluster/ecs52v-usw2-tst",
cluster/ecs52v-usw2-stg",
cluster/ecs52v-usw2-prd",`

    for i, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match[1], "found at line", i)
    }
}
```